# Absolute elements outside div are hidden when sliding

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

Good evening,

I have a piece of code that toggles a drop-down menu. In the menu, there are some DIVs positioned 'outside' their containing DIV. A jsFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/nGSPg/3/

The problem is, when the 'sliding' animation is playing, the triangles are hidden. My questions are:

- Why is this?
- How do I solve this? I want the triangles to slide down and up just like their containing div.

Thanks in advance, 
Silox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: The real problem actually is that slide() sets **overflow** to **hidden** on the element, so it will hide anything outside of it. When it is finished it will remove it making them appear again.

---

Because the triangles have *position:absolute*, they will only appear after the slide is finsished. 
To fix this I would give them a **position: relative** and move them outside that box and **put it all in a container div that itself gets the slide applied to it**.

The updated HTML:

```
<span class="toggle">Admin</span> |

<div class="slidetoggle">
  <div class="triangle-big"></div>
  <div class="triangle-small"></div>

  <div class="slideHolder"> <a href="" title="" target="_blank">Forum</a>
    <br /> <a href="" title="" target="_blank">Website</a>
  </div>
</div> <span class="toggle">My account</span>

<div class="slidetoggle">
  <div class="triangle-big"></div>
  <div class="triangle-small"></div>

  <div class="slideHolder"> <a href="" title="">My profile</a>
    <br /> <a href="" title="">User panel</a>
    <br /> <a href="" title="">Log out</a>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>​
```

and the CSS:

```
.toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px 2px 0px 3px;
}

.slidetoggle {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.slideHolder{
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    padding:10px;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c8c8c8;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c8c8c8;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c8c8c8;
    text-align: left;
}

#login-links {
    padding: 2px 10px 0px 3px;
}

.triangle-big {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #C8C8C8;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
    left: 8px;
    z-index: 99;
}

.triangle-small {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
    position: relative;
    top:1px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
}​
```

[Here's a forked example that shows it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/tSXgG/)

Comment: Accepted answer - thank you! The 'hiding' problem wasn't because of the absolute position, when I positioned it in the DIV, it was visible. The slide uses - apparently - overflow: hidden, which caused elements outside the DIV to hide. You're solution still works though!

Comment: Yes, you're right. The slide does force that overflow value onto the container as well. Good call.